# Confluence User Mention Wiki Markup

Tags: confluence-rest-api

I am creating Blog articles on Confluence via the REST API. I'd like to use User Mentions within the article, e.g. the same thing as @Ben Rogers would give you when posting directly through the UI.

I can't find anything in the documentation so I'm guessing it'll have to be a more manual process, any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the user mention macro in a Confluence page, you can then click on the "Open in source editor" button and you will see the code inserted looks like this:

```
<ac:link>
  <ri:user ri:userkey="ff10413554ef222e01222669b976001a"/>
</ac:link>
```

So you need to know the userkey for the users you want to mention, you can look this up in the database, see following link:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/277551/find-user-by-resource-identifier. Then just add those links with the corresponding userkey to the html code of your page.